# Add ripple effect to a disabled button

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, quasar-framework

I have a button which would enable and disable based on the mandatory form fields. When the button is enabled, clicking would have the ripple effect.

I want to add the ripple effect when the button is disabled as well. I tried something similar to the following code in the Vue Playground.
I am using Vue3 with Composition API.

[Vue playground code](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

How to enable the click event and add the ripple effect when the button is disabled?

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

//This is based on the form fields
const disableSubmit = ref(true)

//const rippleEffect = computed(() => (disableSubmit.value ? "btn-ripple" : ""))

</script>

<template>
  <button :disabled="disableSubmit" class="btn-ripple">
    <span>Submit</span>
  </button>
</template>

<style>

.btn-ripple {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 22px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background: #00a1d4;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-ripple:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40);
  }
}

.btn-ripple:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}

.btn-ripple:after {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-ripple:focus:after {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please put code IN the question even if it is somewhere 'functional' so it can be seen when that external goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `disabled` HTML attribute means that your button won't be focused, hence the `.btn-ripple:focus` state won't ever be achieved.

I guess, the easiest way to do what you want is to imitate the disabling, i.e., to have something like `if (disableSubmit.value) return` inside your click handler, while the button itself will stay enabled from the pure HTML point of view.

You'll also might want to change the class to something like `:class="{ 'btn-ripple': true, 'btn-ripple-disabled': disableSubmit }"`, if you need to add some styling to the disabled button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used a similar approach to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to not use all that design styles and keep using the default provided by Quasar but use the solution below by avoiding the `click` event in case of the **disabled** status.

```
<q-btn round color="primary" @click="null" icon="card_giftcard"></q-btn>
```